# Constructor returning null for class method during JUnit Test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public classA() {

    public String getName() {
        return "ClassA";
    }
}

public classB() {

    public String getName() {
        return "ClassB";
    }
}

public ClassC {

    List<> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    public ClassC(final ClassA classA, final ClassB classB) {
        list.add(classA);
        print(classA.getName()); //prints null
        list.add(classB);
    }
}
```

——————

I am trying to test class C as follows,

```
@Mock
private ClassA classA;

@Mock
private ClassB classB;

@InjectMocks
private ClassC classC;
```

It seems to injecting the classes in ClassC constructor but returns null when extracting the data from inside those classes. Is there a way to retrieve that getName() String successfully inside ClassC constructor through unit test?

Comment: The above doesnt even compile. You cant have a method inside a constructor, so that code doesnt make sense. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code is for demo purpose and shouldn’t compile. I m just trying to print the String returned by the classA.getName() in the constructor for debugging.

Comment: Don't do that. We have no idea about your thoughts when you give us pseudo code to then ask about a real java code problem. Seriously, read that link I gave you. And then improve your question. All relevant facts need to be in the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Mockito works by design. When you create a mock object e.g.:

```java
@Mock
private ClassB classB;
```

Mockito will create another class using ByteBuddy and compile that in runtime. Another thing that all methods of that class will be intercepted. The default interceptor always will return `null` value or the default for atomic values. E.g `0` for `int`.

It doesn't matter the original method always returns the same Stirng. Mock object will return `null`.

In short Mockito will create a totally different class and an object of that class.

So you need mock methods like

```java
when(classB.getName(any())).thenReturn("classB");
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I appreciate it. In that case what if I do not want to @Mock it anymore with the aim of returning the original string, if I do
```
public TestClass {
@Autowired
private ClassC classC;
}
```
The ClassC should technically take care of other classes since the the constructor is @Autowired but it doesn’t and still doesn’t returns null.

Answer (score 0):

the `getName` method in classA and ClassB is of type void. You might change them to return `String` and see if that helps.

Just fyi is getName() on a class a overloaded method, please see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName() so you might also just remove the `getName` methods in classA and ClassB.

Please let me know if this is useful.

-Kaj :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kaj. It should have been a String I have updated it my bad. ClassA and ClassB are implementing an interface and overriding method to return there own name.

Comment: :) Does ```print(classA.getName());``` print what you expect after the change or still "null"?

Comment: Still null seems to be something wrong with the way ClassA and ClassB are being injected in unit test.